# DataGrid inside ListView as item template

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid

I'm having some trouble displaying ListView with DataGrids inside it (as item templates). The problem is that column widths in DataGrid are getting wrong size and not stretching to fill whole control width.

Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest1"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <x:Array x:Key="ListViewItems"
                 Type="{x:Type system:String}">
            <system:String>1</system:String>
            <system:String>2</system:String>
        </x:Array>

        <x:Array x:Key="DataGridItems"
                 Type="{x:Type system:String}">
            <system:String>1</system:String>
            <system:String>2</system:String>
            <system:String>3</system:String>
        </x:Array>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateWidthDataGrid">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource DataGridItems}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"
                                        Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"
                                        Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateWidthDataGrid}"
                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource ListViewItems}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result looks like this:
[image: MainWindow screenshot]

How can i get columns to fill the control width in this scenario?

**UPDATED**

Following Ciccio's answer I have set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property at ListViewItem.

```xml
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateWithDataGrid}"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource ListViewItems}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                        Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

The result is stil not satisfying:
[image: Another screenshot]

(I also had to set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` for `DataGrid`.)

Compare this with the same `DataGrid` put outside of the `ListView` like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource DataGridItems}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"
                                Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"
                                Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Third screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that ItemPanel doesn't stretch its content. You should fix it setting the property `HorizontalContentAlignment` for the **ListBoxItem**:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateWidthDataGrid}"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource ListViewItems}" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:**

According with what i've found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898471/wpf-datagrid-columns-width-fail-in-listbox), probably you'll fix this problem using a workaround: (binding the **Width** of the datagrid to the **ActualWidth** of the **ListViewItemPresenter** and adjusting the Margin)

```
    <x:Array x:Key="ListViewItems" Type="{x:Type system:String}">
        <system:String>1</system:String>
        <system:String>2</system:String>
    </x:Array>

    <x:Array x:Key="DataGridItems" Type="{x:Type system:String}">
        <system:String>1</system:String>
        <system:String>2</system:String>
        <system:String>3</system:String>
    </x:Array>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateWidthDataGrid">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{StaticResource DataGridItems}" Margin="-5,0,0,0"
                  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsPresenter}}}"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateWidthDataGrid}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ListViewItems}">

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! HorizontalContentAlignment makes some effect on DataGrid but columns are still getting wrong width. See updated question.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Another issue though is the glitch with horizontal scroll bar appearing and disappearing when I resize the window. I think there must be a way to disable it somehow with HorizontalScrollBarVisibility